# How can I differentiate pick, pack and out in odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

Actually I'm trying to display color in the lines of picking, only in the picking but i can't differentiate by state and I don't know which is the field to differentiate it

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='move_ids_without_package']/tree" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="decoration-success">picking_code == 'internal' and quantity_done &gt;= product_uom_qty</attribute>
                </xpath>
```

But the picking_code 'internal' is for the two states pack and pick, how can I differentiate pick, pack and out?

Answer (score 0):

Add new char field with store=True and related with `picking_id.picking_type_id.sequence_code`

`sequence_code` will help us to identify PICK & PACK types of inventory documents.

Change the field in your code from `picking_code` to your new field.

JFI, picking_code will be internal for both pick & pack operations. So that field will not help you.